# My script for detecting online/offline event is not working. Always shows the user as online

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to create a javascript to detect on and offline event when a user login to their account, but am currently challenge on how to get offline event to work, since my event icon shows green even when the user is offline, in my case what is the best way to go about this ? is this issue from my script ? or html or css ?here is my script

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var user_status = document.getElementById("user_status");
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
    
      function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
        var condition = navigator.onLine ? "status_online" : "offline";
    
        user_status.className = condition;
        user_status.innerHTML = condition.toUpperCase();
    
        log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Event: " + event.type + "; Status: " + condition);
      }
    
      window.addEventListener('status_online',  updateOnlineStatus);
      window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
    });
  
  </script>
```

my css status icon styling

```
/* ---------------------------------- */
/*  user status icon
------------------------------------- */
.user_status {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 2.5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.user_status.status_online {
  background-color: #38b653;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is my html to display status icon

```
<div class="profiles_content">
                <div class="relative uk-transition-toggle overflow-hidden">
               <div uk-form-custom class="w-full py-5" >
                <div class="profile_avatar">
                  
                    <div class="profile_avatar_holder">
                      
                        <img src="{{ profile_image }}" alt="">
                    
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="user_status status_online"></div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("user_status")` your code doesn't have an element with an id of `user_status`.

Comment: Perhaps start by using your browser's dev tools inspect facility to get rid of the JS errors. Then look up the events you can listen for. I don't know of status_online as an event but online is an event you can listen for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine) page there is no `status_online` event, but there is however, `online` event

Another mistake you have is there is no element with id `user_status`, so you'll need either add an id or use `querySelector(".user_status")` instead.

Also, you are trying to replace entire `className` with a single name, which means class name `user_status` will be removed from the element, but your css is depended on that name.

So in the situations like this, it's probably a better approach to use an attribute instead of class name, this way you don't have to worry about previous "status" class, this especially handy if you have more than 2 conditions.

```js
const user_status = document.getElementById("user_status");

function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
  let condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

  //dataset is simpliest to use, it automatically adds attribute to the element
  user_status.dataset.status = condition;

  console.log("Event: " + event.type, " Status: " + condition);
}
window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);

updateOnlineStatus({}); //set initial status
```

```css
/* ---------------------------------- */
/*  user status icon
------------------------------------- */
.user_status {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 2.5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
/* this kind of redundent */
/*  visibility: hidden; */
}

.user_status[data-status="online"] {
  background-color: #38b653;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* ignore this */
.profile_avatar
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile_avatar">

    <div class="profile_avatar_holder">

        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj" alt="">

    </div>

  <div id="user_status" class="user_status"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mention that the OP used a class ".user_status" instead of an id "#user_status" in their html/js.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution didn't work, Am still  having the same problem  after i had change script and also when i had update my css to your code, the user online icon still stays green when am logout  and  when i check in the console i don't see any errors !

Comment: @vanowm what do you suggest i do ? to debug this  issue , it doesn't pass the condition when you switch offline, I  mean when user logout the icon just stays green. instead of it switching to gray?

Comment: If the snippet works for your here, then it's something you do wrong in your code, without seeing it, nobody could possibly tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Yes the snippet work  as I have noted ,but once am logout it should turn gray but yet it stays green ! I stated in my question that this was my issue in the first place !

Comment: where/how do you logout? Have you examined the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine) page about how it works in different browsers?

Comment: Ok, reading your original question again, you are talking about some "account", yet your code has absolutely no indication there any kind of accounts involved, it tries show online/offline of the browser itself.